# Jquery Json dynamic variable name generation

Tags: jquery, json, dynamic, variables

I make a jquery .ajax call and I'm expecting a json result.
The catch is, if there are say 5 authors, I'll get author_details_0, author_details_1, author_details_2, etc.... How can I dynamically construct the name of the variable to retrieve from json ? I don't know how many authors I'll get, there could be hundreds.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/authordetails/show_my_details/",
data: af_pTempString,
dataType: "json",
beforeSend: function() {
},
success: function(jsonData) {
    console.log("Incoming from backend : " + jsonData.toSource());
    if(jsonData.AuthorCount)
    {
        console.log("Number of Authors : " + jsonData.AuthorCount);
        for (i = 0; i < jsonData.AuthorCount; i++)
        {
            temp = 'author_details_' + i; <-------------------This is the name of the variable I'm expecting.
            console.log("Farm information : " + eval(jsonData.temp) ); <----- This doesn't work, how can I get jsonData.author_details_2 for example, 'coz I don't know how many authors are there, there could be hundreds.
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this !
Much appreciated.

Comment: why do you need author_details_0, 1, 2, etc?

Comment: How are you generating the json?

Comment: I'm using dJango at the backend. The data model I've created has Author & related Author_Details table. Given an publisher id, I query and get the set of Authors which I simple serialize - json_serializer.serialize(allAuthors, ensure_ascii=False).

This does not serialize the Author Details, hence I have to loop through the author object array and create them manually, hence author_details_XX where XX is the author primary key.

I'm not sure if there is a way to bundle an Author & other details it has as a single JSON Array object. If there is I'd gladly retrofit my code, since its be cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access object properties in two ways. First is dot notation, as in object.property. You can also use bracket notation, as in object['property']. No need for eval here:

```
 var propName = 'author_details_' + i;
 alert('Details for author ' + i + ' = ' + jsonData[propName];
```

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) addresses your assumption at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it !

Instead of using "temp" -
temp = 'author_details_' + i;
and then doing -
eval(jsonData.temp)

Just this works - eval("jsonData.author_details_" + i)

Since the data is from the database, it is safe, since I put everything in database after checking. Hence eval will not pose a security threat.

If you have any more solutions, I'd be glad to hear them !

Answer (score 0):

why not store the json as an array? instead of:

```
{
    "author_details_1":
    {
        ...
    },
    "author_details_2":
    {
        ...
    },
    "author_details_3":
    {
        ...
    },
    "author_details_4":
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

try

```
{
    "author_details":
    [
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

Then you can access it with author_details[i].

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem with jQuery and $.ajax function. Solved by defining the 'data' object outside of the $.ajax function :

```
var data = new Object();
data.ContentNodeID = button.siblings('.ContentNodeID').val();
data.ContentObjectID = button.siblings('.ContentObjectID').val();
data.ActionAddToBasket = '';
data['eZOption['+$('[name=printFormatAttributeId]').val()+'][]'] = $('.eZOption').val();

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: button.parent().attr('action'),
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
                 button.siblings('.addtobasket_success').css('display', 'inline');
                 $('#shop_button').removeClass('disabled');
                 $('#shop_button').removeAttr('disabled');
             },
    error: function(data) {
                 button.siblings('.addtobasket_failure').css('display', 'inline');
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = './json/demo_'+var+'.net';
$.getJSON(url, function(result){
    alert(result[0].name);
});
```

OR

```
$.getJSON('./json/demo_'+var+'.net', function(result){
    alert(result[0].name);
});
```